# Probability of a weapon being detected at airports

Tags: probability

In a city, **80%** of the air travelings take place via airport C and the rest are through airport D.  The security of Airport C is successful **95%** of times in detecting weapons carried by passengers and Airport D is successful **90%** of times in detecting weapons. 
If a passenger carries a weapon, what is the probability that it will be detected?

My work:

Let C represent the probability that an air traveling takes place at airport C. **P(C)=0.8**
Let D represent the probability that an air traveling takes place at airport D. **P(D)=0.2**
Let W represent the probability that a weapon is detected. **P(W)**

**P(W|C)= 0.95** and **P(W|D)=0.9**, then

**P(W) = P(W∩C) + P(W∩D) = P(W|C) * P(C) + P(W|D) * P(D) = 0.95*0.8 + 0.9*0.2 = 0.76 + 0.18 = 0.94** , but the answer indicates 0.52 as the probability of a weapon being detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these are the exact parameters in your assignment, your work is correct. The given answer seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes, this was the exact information given in the question. Thank you very much, what a relief!